# Psql -c está deixando o nome da minha tabela em minúsculo

Tags: postgresql, administração-postgresql, postgresql-10

Olá,

Estou executando o seguinte comando:

```
psql -d copia-local -U postgres -c "COPY "Questions" FROM '/home/pedro/Documents/PostGre/data/cooked/Questions_cooked.txt' WITH DELIMITER '|' NULL AS ''"

ERROR:  relation "questions" does not exist
```

O interessante é que se eu executo o comando dentro do banco de dados do **Postgresql**, funciona:

```
copia-local=# COPY "Questions" FROM '/home/pedro/Documents/PostGre/data/cooked/Questions_cooked.txt' WITH DELIMITER '|' NULL AS '';
COPY 1342
```

Pesquisei sobre os parâmetros do psql mas não achei nada sobre respeitar o nome da tabela, parece que quando eu rodo pelo psql ele da lowercase no nome da tabela.

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que fazer ?

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o caractere de escape no nome de sua tabela:

```
psql -d copia-local -U postgres -c "COPY \"Questions\" FROM '/home/pedro/Documents/PostGre/data/cooked/Questions_cooked.txt' WITH DELIMITER '|' NULL AS ''"
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado !